# Statistics on package usage

Tags: miktex, texlive, package-writing, ctan

Is there any way I can get an overview or at least any indication on how many people downloaded/installed a package from CTAN, MiKTeX and/or TeXLive?

I'm asking because I have recently made several packages, and I would like to know if they're getting used, and in turn which should be prioritized in maintaining and the like. Also It's always nice to know approximately how many are using it.

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Considering the fact that a full installation is recommended, and that people load packages just for the *lolz* without using them ... That statistic would be pretty useless.

Comment: A full installation is recommended?! But why? How does make sense?

Comment: I use and recommend a full installation because disk space is not an issue anymore (MiKTeX is approx 5 GB when installed on my system, less than a decent full HD movie in H.264 with surround sound). In addition, it's very annoying (at least to me) if you want to try something new and some package dependencies or new packages are missing.

Comment: But wouldn't this make it such a hassle to keep your packages up to date?

Comment: Package manager available for both distributions, taking care of package updates. New packages that go to TL get installed with an update (by default).

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman You could do it like the `cleanthesis` package and ask your users to sent you a postcard :)

Comment: @samcarter Great idea! I'll just lock it, so that they send me a postcard, and then I'll reply with an activation code. That way I can just count my postcards!

Answer (score 7):

Speaking for CTAN there are several ways out:

- Distributions like TeXLive and MikTeX
- Downloads from CTAN itself and it's mirrors
- Distribution via DVD

We could in theory count the downloads in the logs of CTAN itself. But already the mirrors are beyound our control.

Having said that, I think that many people use CTAN to read documentation. Thus it would be possible to record the clicks to get an indication of the popularity. Maybe I will do an experiment in this direction...
but don't hold your breath;-)

Comment: Many read the documentation locally installed as well. Or using TeXdoc.net

Comment: @Johannes_B Stefan unfortunately just closed texdoc.net, after Henri suggested he either update or close the site (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44511748#44511748)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Oh, that went by me. Thanks for the note. A bit unfortunate though.